# How to tell the date difference in weeks AND days in python?

Tags: python, datetime

I have an assignment that goes like this:

**"-Ask a user to enter a deadline for their project,**

**-Tell them how many days they have to finish the project,**

**-Give them the answer as a combination of weeks and days."**

I am stuck at the 3rd point.
My code so far goes like this:

```
import datetime

deadlineInput = input ("What's the deadline for your project? (dd/mm/yyyy):")

deadline = datetime.datetime.strptime(deadlineInput, '%d/%m/%Y').date()

currentDate = datetime.date.today()

daysLeft = deadline - currentDate

print("You have " + str(daysLeft) + " left until the deadline")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can't do your homework for you, but there are 7 days in a week, and the modulo (`%`) function might help you

Comment: Is a week any 7 day period, or it a calendar week?

Comment: To add on to @MoxieBall's remark-  note that there are two division operators in python3, `/` and `//`, one of which is far better suited for your problem.

Comment: @MoxieBall thanks for the tip, and this is not real homework, just something I found on the internet and tried to challenge myself but now I'm stuck, I just started learning python 2 days ago.

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: @mentallurg so when i run the code, it gives me the answer only in days, and i need it to be shown in days and weeks, not only days. E.G if the answer is 23 days, how can i make it so it shows 3 weeks and 2 days? Sorry if I'm not clear enough my english is not that good.

Comment: @G.Hyseni: Do you need help, to convert days into weeks? OK, here is a result of 20 years of experience with Python: divide by 7 :)  What is your problem, really?

Answer (score 0):

Use f-strings as it changes variables to a string and reads easier.
So rather than

```
print("You have " + str(daysLeft) + "days left until the deadline")
```

you can use and it will change daysLeft to a string.

```
print(f"You have {daysLeft} days left until the deadline")
```

Also add this code in to help to get the days.

```
#convert to days so you don't have the timestamp
daysLeft = daysLeft.days
```

So it should look like

```
import datetime

deadlineInput = input ("What's the deadline for your project? (dd/mm/yyyy):")

deadline = datetime.datetime.strptime(deadlineInput, '%d/%m/%Y').date()

currentDate = datetime.date.today()

daysLeft = deadline - currentDate

#convert to days so you don't have the timestamp
daysLeft = daysLeft.days

#Todo: homework
weeks = # calculate weeks from daysLeft using %
days = # calculate remainder from daysLeft using //

print(f"You have {weeks} weeks and {days} days left until the deadline")
```

Then go back and refactor to remove camelCase and convert to snake_case e.g. daysLeft to days_left